# Eclipse CDT - shortcut to know which all files include a header file?

Tags: c++, c, header-files, eclipse-cdt

I have a big project. I want to find which all .cpp/.h files include `file1.h` in them. Is there any shortcut key in Eclipse CDT to do this?

Comment: Search in files for '#include "file.h"' in source directory?

Comment: Yes I can do this on a terminal. Was just wondering if I can do it inside eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest the Include Browser view. You can drag a file in there and you get a nice tree which shows all files that include your file, including indirect includes.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, under the search menu, the entry `File...` exists.
Searching there for `#include*"file1.h"` should do the trick.

Optimization suggestions:
`Preferences->General->Keys`, search for `file search` then add the binding `Ctrl+H` for it. This is by default mapped to `C/C++ Search`, so you will have to remove the prior binding or use another hotkey.

If you want to go the extra mile, check out [Practically Macro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/). It should be straight forward to make a "Search including files" macro with it.